# How to return values from pool threads in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to learn multiprocessing in python.
I did the examples on Pyhon page, but now I don't know how to combine those two information of returning values from a pool thread.

A friend of mine send me this code http://pastebin.com/g4BLUTcq but I couldn't figure out how to get values back.

My goal is to have one process constantly recording from a radio receiver and another process to do signal processing while the next recording is already running again.

Perhaps you could give me some hints how to do that.

Best regards,

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

That example code builds it's own thread pool class, when there is already one in python. Check out the very basic example [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html).

slightly modified from docs.python.org:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        my_var = p.map(f, [1, 2, 3])   # This is your return variable now
```

If you actually need to communicate and use queues, check out [this guide](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html) from python module of the week (great tutorial websites).

Edit: you also mention both multiprocessing and threading, in python they are separate things, but they are both coded near the same (there is also a ThreadPool instead of multiprocessing pool if that's what you're more interested in).

Answer (score 0):

Sub-classing the multiprocessing.Process would be one way of doing that. I have written some sample code showing how to start a listener process that sends the recordings it receives to a processing process while using the Queue.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import logging
import random


# recording simlator
def recorder():
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))
        yield 'recording %d' % i
    yield None


# Listener class
class listener(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, source, queue):
        super(listener, self).__init__()
        self.source = source
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        for task in self.source():
            if task is None:
                self.queue.put(None)
                break
            logging.info('Recorded %s' % task)
            self.queue.put(task)
        return


# simulating processing function
def processing_func(task):
    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
    return 'Processed %s' % task


# Processor class
class processor(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, queue, processing_function):
        super(processor, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.processing_function = processing_function

    def run(self):
        while True:
            logging.info('Getting task')
            task = self.queue.get()
            if task is None:
                break
            # print self.queue
            processed_result = self.processing_function(task)
            logging.info(processed_result)
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s  %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # make a queue sending tasks from listener to processor
    new_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    # make a listener
    rec = listener(recorder, new_queue)
    # make a processor
    pro = processor(new_queue, processing_func)

    # start processing and listening
    pro.start()
    rec.start()

    # Finish recording and processing
    rec.join()
    pro.join()
```